# Indefinite article in "Referee! That was a penalty!"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

How would you say?

- Referee! That was **a** penalty!
- Referee! That was penalty!

It is because, in this case, "penalty" is considered as an adjective?

Comment: Penalty is a noun. In the sentence, it is a noun complement.

Comment: The word **a** in "That was **a** penalty" is not a preposition but an *indefinite article*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sentence seems the most natural in the context of a soccer match:

> Referee! That was **a** penalty!

"Penalty" is a countable singular noun, and because of this we place an indefinite article before it.

Example of such usage:

> "But he definitely tripped Andre up, so the referee decided **that was a penalty**." ([Express](http://www.express.co.uk/sport/football/621144/Swansea-2-Bournemouth-2-Garry-Monk-Eddie-Howe-Premier-League), November 2015)

---

We can also say

> Referee! That was **the** penalty!

Here, we use the definite article **the** before "penalty", indicating that the  speaker has in mind a particular penalty, and the referee knows (or is able to deduce from the context) what particular penalty the speaker is talking about.

---

The word "**penalty**" can also be used in a noncount sense:

> That time I hit an entire sleeve of balls into the pond and finished the hole with a Slazenger range ball -- was that a violation?
>
> Trust me, that was **penalty** enough. ([source](http://espn.go.com/golf/story/_/id/13844671/phil-mickelson-one-ball-controversy-presidents-cup-further-exposes-rules-confusion))

Since it's used in a noncount sense here, it takes no article.

Merriam-Webster's entry on **[penalty](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/penalty)** makes a mention of the word's non-count sense

> [noncount] They allowed him to pay back the money without *penalty*.

---

Hence, I guess that the sentence

> Referee! That was penalty!

is also passable, but it has a meaning that is different from the first sentence. Trying to construe a situation in which this statement would fit, I imagine a referee who had made a decision that was formally neutral but in essense hampered the team's ability to play. A player spoke these words, challenging the referee's decision by describing it as "penalty".

An example of this "defining use" of the phrase:

> I inquired of the Customs department why that extra fifteen per cent was imposed, and they said that **that was penalty**. ([Official Report of Debates, House of Commons, volume 175, 1926](https://books.google.ru/books?id=_BslAQAAIAAJ&q=%22that+was+penalty%22&dq=%22that+was+penalty%22&hl=ru&sa=X&redir_esc=y))

Comment: @cape - you're welcome! I forgot about the noncount use of the word, and recalled it only upon searching in Google News.